# Unable to register as developer: Not receiving confirmation code

Tags: confirmation

I'm trying to register as a developer but I'm not receiving confirmation code to my cell phone.
I entered my country code + my phone number in the right form but still, I tried "resend" option couple of times, several phone numbers and still all my tries failed.
Can it be I'm blocked or there is a temporary failure at Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this via google, try this:

Not receiving your Facebook confirmation code?
Text "F" (without quotes) to 32665 and you should instantly receive the code
Hope this helps cut down on some implementation headaches people may be having.
Enter that into the corresponding area under settings on Facebook and boom it all works! (Dont forget to instantly deactivate SMS alerts otherwise you’ll be pestered every time a ‘friend’ mentions what they had for tea, plus you’ll be charged for it too)